# PyCryptodome AES, 'EcbMode' object has no attribute 'encrypt_and_digest'

Tags: python, encryption, aes, pycrypto, pycryptodome

I am using `Pycharm Text Editor` and `PyCryptodome Library` for **encryption of message** using `Advanced Encryption Standard (AES)`. It is also one of the majorly used `Symmetric Encryption Algorithm`. My code of `AES Encryption` was stated below:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
key = os.urandom(16)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
ciphertext, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(message)
```

And I am encountering the error:-

```
AttributeError: 'EcbMode' object has no attribute 'encrypt_and_digest
```

at line:-

```
ciphertext, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(message)
```

I have tried uninstalling the module a couple of times but the error persists.
`Pycharm` does not mark the line with red underscores and I can use `ctrl-click` to go into the source and see that the `encrypt_and_digest()` function exists.

**My question is:-**

Why can't the code go through the compiler?
Is there another module in python that I can use to perform `AES encryption`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Error` we can see that `encrypt_and_digest()` attribute is not available in `ECB (Electronic Code Book)` Mode of `AES Encryption`. So, there are two Solution for your query let's have a look at one by one:-

**1. By Changing Mode:-**

By Changing `mode` to `modern modes` we can use `encrypt_and_digest()` module. Basically `encrypt_and_digest()` module is combination of `encrypt()` and `digest()` Module.

- `encrypt()`:- This module used to `Encrypt` your `Message`
- `digest()`:- This module used to Generate `MAC Tag` of `Message`

```
# List of 'Modern Modes' was given below:-
1. MODE_EAX
2. MODE_CCM
3. MODE_SIV
4. MODE_GCM
5. MODE_OCB
```

Code for the given Scenario Using `EAX Mode` was stated below:-

```
# Import all the Important Libraries
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import os

# 'pad_message()' function declaration for padding purpose.
# Because 'message' length should be always multiple of '16'
def pad_message(message):
  while len(message) % 16 != 0:
    message = message + " "
  return message

# Initialization of 'Key' and 'Message'
key = os.urandom(16)
message = input("Enter your Message for AES Encryption:- ")

# If the length of the message is not multiple of '16' then pad it
message = pad_message(message)

# Print Message, Key and Length of Message before Encryption Process
print("\nMessage:-", message)
print("Key:-", key)
print("Length of the Message:-", len(message))

# Declare New module for AES Encryption in 'EAX' Mode
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_EAX)

# Encrypt 'Message' and Generate 'MAC Tag' Using 'encrypt_and_digest()' method
cipher_text, mac_tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(message.encode('utf-8'))

# Print Encrypted Message 
print("\nEncryption of Message Using AES:-", cipher_text)
print("MAC Tag of our Encrypted Message is:-", mac_tag)
```

```
# Output of Above Code:-
Enter your Message for AES Encryption:- Stack Overflow

Message:- Stack Overflow  
Key:- b'\xf1\x9a\xc1\x12\xdcI7\xc8\xe4\xcf\x1e5\xe4\x93i\xc4'
Length of the Message:- 16

Encryption of Message Using AES:- b'\x97\x0e+\xcb^\x82\xeelhs2_\x90m\x1c+'
MAC Tag of our Encrypted Message is:- b'c!\xb2\xf4\x82\xceT3\x0cM1\x04\x87(y?'
```

**2. Without Changing Mode:-**

If you want to `Encrypt` Using `ECB (Electronic Code Book)` Mode. then we can Use `encrypt()` and `hex()` module.

Code for the given Scenario Using `ECB Mode` was stated below:-

```
# Import all the Important Libraries
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import os

# 'pad_message()' function declaration for padding purpose.
# Because 'message' length should be always multiple of '16'
def pad_message(message):
  while len(message) % 16 != 0:
    message = message + " "
  return message

# Initialization of 'Key' and 'Message'
key = os.urandom(16)
message = input("Enter your Message for AES Encryption:- ")

# If the length of the message is not multiple of '16' then pad it
message = pad_message(message)

# Print Message, Key and Length of Message before Encryption Process
print("\nMessage:-", message)
print("Key:-", key)
print("Length of the Message:-", len(message))

# Declare New module for AES Encryption in 'ECB (Electronic Codebook)' Mode
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)

# Encrypt 'Message'
cipher_text  = cipher.encrypt(message.encode('utf-8'))

# Print Encrypted Message 
print("\nEncryption of Message Using AES:-", cipher_text)
print("Hex of Cipher Text:-", cipher_text.hex())

# Verify by decrypting Cipher Text whether you are recieving same message or not
decrypted_message = cipher.decrypt(cipher_text)
print("\nDecryption of Cipher Text Using AES:-", decrypted_message)
```

```
# Output of Above Code:-
Enter your Message for AES Encryption:- Stack Overflow

Message:- Stack Overflow  
Key:- b'\x94\x88o\xf0\x8f\xbe\xec\x0e\x1e\xdf\x06A\xdf<\xbe\xe3'
Length of the Message:- 16

Encryption of Message Using AES:- b'\xf6c)\xee\xea\x13\xdcX\x9c\x06E\x82~{c\xc6'
Hex of Cipher Text:- f66329eeea13dc589c0645827e7b63c6

The decryption of Cipher Text Using AES:- b'Stack Overflow
```

Hope this Solution helps you.

Comment: Any differences in security when it comes to "NOTE:- hex() and digest() are not same. But it was similar because MAC Tag Generated by digest() was in hex Format." in your opinion?

Comment: Sorry, It was my mistake. `hex()` and `digest()` are totally different modules in terms of Security. Thank you for the spotting light on this mistake. I have updated my Post. Does there is any other mistake?

Answer (score 2):

If you read the documentation you will see that `encrypt_and_digest()` is only supported by the [modern modes](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/modern.html):

- `MODE_CCM`
- `MODE_EAX`
- `MODE_GCM`
- `MODE_SIV`
- `MODE_OCB`

ECB mode really shouldn't be used for anything as it is not [semantically secure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20941/why-shouldnt-i-use-ecb-encryption/20946#20946).